# Report subscription rights to write file

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

[image]

I've done an experiment by specifying the path to be at my local drive and filled up my own username and password, ended up it hitting exception related to no access right.

Second experiment I've tested by sharing the folder at my local drive to everyone within the domain, and this time filled up using another username that have different SSRS role and it worked smoothly.

The role that I have was **Browser** and **Publisher** which should be sufficient. What is exactly mean by **Credentials used to access the file share**?

Comment: How are you specifying the path? UNC path or drive path?

Comment: @WEI_DBA: UNC path